# How can I compute this limit?

Tags: limits

I know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sqrt{2-2\cos(\frac{2\pi}{x})}=2\pi$ but I am unsure about how to compute it by hand.

I the limit of $n$ alone is infinity, obviously, and the limit of $\cos(\frac{2\pi}{x})=1$. Therefore, to me, is it not $n*\sqrt{2-2}=n*0=\infty*0=0?$

Comment: $\ \cos(\frac{2\pi}{x})=1$ are you sure that is x in the nominator?

Comment: Zero times infinity is not zero, it's undefined. It's not good intuition to think of zero times infinity as zero.

Comment: @JoshuaRuiter that's what i was thinking. Should I use lopitals?

Comment: You should not think of "infinity" as a value of a limit. It is just a placeholder for the statement "the function is unbounded as n becomes large." When you think of it this way, things like $0*\infty$ stop making sense, you can't multiply logical statements by numbers. This is good, because they can lead you to incorrect conclusions.

Comment: I think there is typo.  You need to replace $x$ by $n$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\require{cancel}\;n\sqrt{2\left(1-\cos(\frac{2\pi}{n})\right)}=n\sqrt{2 \cdot 2 \sin^2(\frac{\bcancel{2} \pi}{\bcancel{2}n})}=2n\left|\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\right| = 2\pi \cdot \left|\cfrac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})}{\frac{\pi}{n}}\right|$